# Unexpected token encountered when reading value in JSON schema

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I was trying to validate my schema correctness using [JsonSchemaValidator](http://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/) and got the error:

> Unexpected token encountered when reading value for 'CWD'. Expected StartObject, got String. Path 'properties.details.oneOf[0].properties.CWD', line 278, position 43.

The full JSON schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "definitions": {
    "validString": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/validString",
      "minLength": 1,
      "not": {
        "enum": [
          "<N/A>"
        ]
      }
    },
    "validInteger": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/validInteger",
      "minimum": 0,
      "not": {
        "enum": [
          -1
        ]
      }
    },
    "validPath": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "dev": {
          "title": "Device minor and major ID",
          "$ref": "#/definitions/validString"
        },
        "file_type": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/validString"
        },
        "gname": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/validString"
        },
        "inode": {
          "title": "inode number associated with the recorded file or directory",
          "$ref": "#/definitions/validInteger"
        },
        "item": {
          "title": "Item out of total items",
          "$ref": "#/definitions/validInteger"
        },
        "mode": {
          "title": "File or directory permissions",
          "$ref": "#/definitions/validString"
        },
        "name": {
          "title": "File or directory which was passed as an argument",
          "$ref": "#/definitions/validString"
        },
        "node": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/validString"
        },
        "ogid": {
          "title": "Object owner's group ID",
          "$ref": "#/definitions/validInteger"
        },
        "ouid": {
          "title": "Object owner's user ID",
          "$ref": "#/definitions/validInteger"
        },
        "rdev": {
          "title": "Device identifier for special files",
          "$ref": "#/definitions/validString"
        },
        "type": {
          "title": "Record type",
          "$ref": "#/definitions/validString"
        },
        "uname": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/validString"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "node",
        "ouid",
        "name",
        "uname",
        "file_type",
        "type",
        "rdev",
        "dev",
        "item",
        "mode",
        "gname",
        "inode",
        "ogid"
      ]
    },
    "validCwd": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "cwd": {
          "title": "Current working directory",
          "$ref": "#/definitions/validString"
        },
        "node": {
          "title": "Current working directory",
          "$ref": "#/definitions/validString"
        },
        "type": {
          "enum": [
            "CWD"
          ],
          "title": "Record type",
          "$ref": "#/definitions/validString"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "node",
        "type",
        "cwd"
      ]
    },
    "validSyscall": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "a0": {
          "title": "1st argument of the system call",
          "$ref": "#/definitions/validString"
        },
        "a1": {
          "title": "2nd argument of the system call",
          "$ref": "#/definitions/validString"
        },
        "a2": {
          "title": "3rd argument of the system call",
          "$ref": "#/definitions/validString"
        },
        "a3": {
          "title": "4th argument of the system call",
          "$ref": "#/definitions/validString"
        },
        "arch": {
          "title": "CPU architecture",
          "$ref": "#/definitions/validString"
        },
        "auid": {
          "title": "Audit user ID",
          "$ref": "#/definitions/validString"
        },
        "egid": {
          "title": "Effective group ID",
          "$ref": "#/definitions/validInteger"
        },
        "euid": {
          "title": "Effective user ID",
          "$ref": "#/definitions/validInteger"
        },
        "exe": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/validString"
        },
        "exit": {
          "title": "Exit code returned by the system call",
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "fsgid": {
          "title": "File system group ID",
          "$ref": "#/definitions/validInteger"
        },
        "fsuid": {
          "title": "File system user ID",
          "$ref": "#/definitions/validInteger"
        },
        "gid": {
          "title": "Group ID",
          "$ref": "#/definitions/validInteger"
        },
        "gname": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/validString"
        },
        "items": {
          "title": "Number of path records in the event",
          "$ref": "#/definitions/validInteger"
        },
        "key": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/validString"
        },
        "node": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/validString"
        },
        "pid": {
          "title": "Process ID",
          "$ref": "#/definitions/validInteger"
        },
        "pname": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/validString"
        },
        "ppid": {
          "title": "Parent process ID",
          "$ref": "#/definitions/validInteger"
        },
        "ses": {
          "title": "Session ID",
          "$ref": "#/definitions/validString"
        },
        "sgid": {
          "title": "Set group ID",
          "$ref": "#/definitions/validInteger"
        },
        "success": {
          "title": "System call succeeded or not",
          "$ref": "#/definitions/validString"
        },
        "suid": {
          "title": "Set user ID",
          "$ref": "#/definitions/validInteger"
        },
        "syscall": {
          "title": "Type of system call",
          "$ref": "#/definitions/validInteger"
        },
        "tty": {
          "title": "Terminal",
          "$ref": "#/definitions/validString"
        },
        "type": {
          "title": "Record type",
          "enum": [
            "SYSCALL"
          ],
          "$ref": "#/definitions/validString"
        },
        "uid": {
          "title": "User ID",
          "$ref": "#/definitions/validInteger"
        },
        "uname": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/validString"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "fsuid",
        "tty",
        "ses",
        "uid",
        "syscall",
        "pid",
        "uname",
        "gname",
        "sgid",
        "auid",
        "suid",
        "gid",
        "exit",
        "ppid",
        "type",
        "node",
        "a1",
        "a0",
        "a3",
        "a2",
        "pname",
        "euid",
        "key",
        "arch",
        "exe",
        "success",
        "items",
        "fsgid",
        "egid"
      ]
    }
  },
  "properties": {
    "component": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/validString"
    },
    "description": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/validString"
    },
    "details": {
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "additionalProperties": false,
          "properties": {
            "CWD": "#/definitions/validCwd",
            "SYSCALL": "#/definitions/validSyscall"
          },
          "required": [
            "SYSCALL",
            "CWD"
          ],
          "type": "object"
        },
        {
          "additionalProperties": false,
          "properties": {
            "CWD": "#/definitions/validCwd",
            "SYSCALL": "#/definitions/validSyscall",
            "PATH0": "#/definitions/validPath"
          },
          "required": [
            "SYSCALL",
            "PATH0",
            "CWD"
          ],
          "type": "object"
        },
        {
          "additionalProperties": false,
          "properties": {
            "CWD": "#/definitions/validCwd",
            "SYSCALL": "#/definitions/validSyscall",
            "PATH0": "#/definitions/validPath",
            "PATH1": "#/definitions/validPath"
          },
          "required": [
            "SYSCALL",
            "PATH0",
            "PATH1",
            "CWD"
          ],
          "type": "object"
        }
      ],
      "type": "object"
    },
    "event_type": {
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "action": {
          "title": "Event action",
          "enum": [
            "mkdir",
            "open",
            "rmdir",
            "unlink"
          ],
          "$ref": "#/definitions/validString"
        },
        "type": {
          "title": "Event type",
          "$ref": "#/definitions/validString"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "action",
        "type"
      ],
      "type": "object"
    },
    "local_timestamp": {
      "title": "Event creation time",
      "$ref": "#/definitions/validString"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "details",
    "local_timestamp",
    "component",
    "event_type",
    "description"
  ],
  "type": "object"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you are defining a schema property by reference to a type defined elsewhere within a JSONschema, you must use the "$ref" directive.

Additionally, when referencing internally in this manner, the property you are defining is by definition an object, so must be enclosed in braces.

So, if you change

```
"CWD": "#/definitions/validCwd"
```

to

```
"CWD": { "$ref":"#/definitions/validCwd" }
```

this will resolve the error you are getting. However, you will get the same error on the next property *SYSCALL*.

So you need to change all instances of

```
"<NNN>": "#/definitions/valid<Nnn>"
```

in your schema to

```
"<NNN>": { "$ref":"#/definitions/valid<Nnn>" }
```